Select a value in a json column
I have a column called Metadata which contains a series of data with this sort of structure:

{"templating":{"template":{"uuid":"810f7345-e4d2-445b-843b-eb038uwh48b5","name":"finance_template_reminder_24h"},"language":"eng","country":""}}

When writing this query I only want to extract the name of the template. The one above is named finance_template_reminder_24h but there are others.
How do I unpack this in a select statement.
Sample:
select m.contact_id, m.metadata ->>'templating' -> 'name' as template
from messages m

Error:
Error running query: operator does not exist: text ->> unknown LINE 1: ...ery ID: adhoc */ select m.contact_id, m.metadata ->>'templa... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Thanks

Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Some differences in syntax and functionality.)

It's pretty clear from the error message and the JSON path syntax that the OP is using PostgreSQL, not MySQL. I have removed the mysql tag.

To access the name field inside templating -> template, you can use the following query if you have the JSON type column:
SELECT 
    m.contact_id, 
    m.metadata -> 'templating' -> 'template' ->> 'name' AS template_name
FROM messages m;

Explanation:

-> is used to navigate into the JSON object.
->> is used to extract a text value from a JSON object.

So in your case, you've to traverse metadata -> 'templating'-> 'template' and then extract the value of the name field using ->> 'name'.
Tested in PostGreSQL

Edited as per the comment
if the metadata column not be in JSONB format and is of type TEXT rather than JSON or JSONB, you need to cast it to JSON or JSONB in your query before using the -> and ->> operators.
Like-
SELECT 
    m.contact_id, 
    (m.metadata::jsonb) -> 'templating' -> 'template' ->> 'name' AS template_name
FROM messages m;


I get the following:
Error running query: operator does not exist: text -> unknown LINE 1: ...ery ID: adhoc */ select m.contact_id, m.metadata -> 'templa... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Do I need to cast it as a text

Btw thanks for the arrow notation explanation. Now, it makes a lot of sense.

did you check my Edited answer, isn't it helpful? –

Yes it was. Thank you.
